# Не работает кириллица в glassfish

Tags: java-ee, glassfish

Никак не могу найти решение корректного отображения русских символов в glassfish.
Вывожу текст в сервлете так:
     response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("текст");
В итоге получаю вместо кириллицы знаки вопроса. Кто сталкивался с подобным подскажите как решить проблему.

Comment: открой страницу в браузере хром, нажми на кнопку настроек -> дополнительные инструменты -> кодировка ->юникод(ютф-8), помогает?

Comment: Нет, не помогает.